# Getting concurrent modification exception when doing Hibernate.initialize() in spring jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot app with spring data jpa. I am getting concurrent modification exception when i am looping through the objects.

when I looping through submission.getPages() i am getting concurrentModificationException.

i tired with checking null and empty but no luck

```
@Override
    public void processCopyAttachmentsToProcessAttachments(int processId) {
        Optional<Process> processOpt = processRepository.findById(processId);
        if (processOpt.isEmpty()) {

            return;
        }
        Process process = processOpt.get();
        Hibernate.initialize(process.getSubmissons());
        List<Submission> submissions = process.getSubmissons();
        if (submissions == null || submissions.isEmpty())
            return;

        for (Submission submission : submissions) {
            Hibernate.initialize(submission.getPages());        
            if (submission.getPages() == null || submission.getPages().isEmpty())
                return;
            for (SubmissionPage submissionPage : submission.getPages()) {           
                Hibernate.initialize(submissionPage.getAttachments());
                if (submissionPage.getAttachments() == null || submissionPage.getAttachments().isEmpty())
                    return;         
                for (SubmissionPageAttachment submissionPageAttachment : submissionPage.getAttachments()) {
                    ProcessAttachment processAttachment = new ProcessAttachment();
                    processAttachment.setDocumentId(submissionPageAttachment.getDocumentId());
                    processAttachment.setDocumentType(submissionPageAttachment.getDocumentType());
                    processAttachment.setProcess(process);
                    processAttachmentRepository.save(processAttachment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure if it is gonna work or not but can you just try to convert foreach loop to a regular for loop? Exception happens because of, as the name suggests, concurrent modifications to the content of the `submission.getPages` while iterating it.

Comment: I changed from for each loop to regular loop it's worked for me.. Thanks @Mensur

Comment: You can read more about ConcurrentModificationException [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your question one more time, I think the main culprit is `Hibernate.initialize`. Because it modifies the object that is passed.

Here's the source code of the method. As we clearly see, it modifies their state and since we know that `ConcurrentModificationException` happens when the content is altered while iteration, this is obviously the reason.

```java
    public static void initialize(Object proxy) throws HibernateException {
        if ( proxy == null ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( proxy instanceof HibernateProxy ) {
            ( (HibernateProxy) proxy ).getHibernateLazyInitializer().initialize();
        }
        else if ( proxy instanceof PersistentCollection ) {
            ( (PersistentCollection) proxy ).forceInitialization();
        }
        else if ( proxy instanceof PersistentAttributeInterceptable ) {
            final PersistentAttributeInterceptable interceptable = (PersistentAttributeInterceptable) proxy;
            final PersistentAttributeInterceptor interceptor = interceptable.$$_hibernate_getInterceptor();
            if ( interceptor instanceof EnhancementAsProxyLazinessInterceptor ) {
                ( (EnhancementAsProxyLazinessInterceptor) interceptor ).forceInitialize( proxy, null );
            }
        }
    }
```

When using a regular for loop, it accesses an object at a time from the collection, hence it gets no exceptions.